# stretch quadrilateral to fit rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, transformation, perspective, viewport3d

I am working on a WPF application, which has to allow a user to define any quadrilateral shape to serve as a cropping area for camera frame. This is accomplished by overlaying video stream with four points connected with lines to visualize which area should be used in the output image.

As a second step, which is causing me trouble, I would like to show a result of transforming selected quadrilateral into a rectangle. I have managed to do this using opencv's [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.0/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) function, but this proved to be slow (processor heavy).

I believe it can also be done with WPF (GPU accelerated) using `Viewport3D` and 3D transformations. I have found a very helpful [article](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/08/250638.html) which led me to the following code

```
<Viewport3D x:Name="canvasViewPort">
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <OrthographicCamera Position="0.5 0.5 1" LookDirection="0 0 -1" UpDirection="0 1 0" Width="1" />
    </Viewport3D.Camera>
    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>
    <Viewport2DVisual3D>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
            <MatrixTransform3D x:Name="canvas3dTransform" />
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 0 0, 1 1 0" TextureCoordinates="0 1, 0 0, 1 1, 1 0" TriangleIndices="0 2 1, 2 3 1"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <DiffuseMaterial Brush="White" Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
        <Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" Margin="0" Width="{Binding ResolutionX}" Height="{Binding ResolutionY}">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImg}"  />
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>
```

And

```
protected void Transform()
{
    double targetWidth  = canvasViewPort.ActualWidth,  xScale = targetWidth  / ResolutionX,
           targetHeight = canvasViewPort.ActualHeight, yScale = targetHeight / ResolutionY;

    var points3d = new Point3D[4];
    if (EditorMode || Corners == null || Corners.Count < 4)
    {   //fit canvas in parent container without warping to allow Corners edition
        points3d[0] = Point2dTo3d(canvasViewPort, new Point(0, 0));
        points3d[1] = Point2dTo3d(canvasViewPort, new Point(0, targetHeight));
        points3d[2] = Point2dTo3d(canvasViewPort, new Point(targetWidth, 0));
        points3d[3] = Point2dTo3d(canvasViewPort, new Point(targetWidth, targetHeight));
    }
    else
    {   //get warped points, Corners indices order is to reflect convention used in the linked blog post
        points3d[0] = Point2dTo3d(canvasViewPort, new Point(Corners[0].X * xScale, Corners[0].Y * yScale));
        points3d[1] = Point2dTo3d(canvasViewPort, new Point(Corners[3].X * xScale, Corners[3].Y * yScale));
        points3d[2] = Point2dTo3d(canvasViewPort, new Point(Corners[1].X * xScale, Corners[1].Y * yScale));
        points3d[3] = Point2dTo3d(canvasViewPort, new Point(Corners[2].X * xScale, Corners[2].Y * yScale));
    }

    var A = new Matrix3D();
    A.M11 = points3d[2].X - points3d[0].X;
    A.M12 = points3d[2].Y - points3d[0].Y;
    A.M21 = points3d[1].X - points3d[0].X;
    A.M22 = points3d[1].Y - points3d[0].Y;
    A.OffsetX = points3d[0].X;
    A.OffsetY = points3d[0].Y;

    double den = A.M11 * A.M22 - A.M12 * A.M21;
    double a =  (A.M22 * points3d[3].X - A.M21 * points3d[3].Y +
                 A.M21 * A.OffsetY - A.M22 * A.OffsetX) / den;
    double b =  (A.M11 * points3d[3].Y - A.M12 * points3d[3].X +
                 A.M12 * A.OffsetX - A.M11 * A.OffsetY) / den;

    var B = new Matrix3D();
    B.M11 = a / (a + b - 1);
    B.M22 = b / (a + b - 1);
    B.M14 = B.M11 - 1;
    B.M24 = B.M22 - 1;

    canvas3dTransform.Matrix = B * A;
}

Point3D Point2dTo3d(Viewport3D vp, Point pt)
{
    var cam = (OrthographicCamera)canvasViewPort.Camera;
    double x = cam.Width / vp.ActualWidth  * (pt.X - vp.ActualWidth / 2)  + cam.Position.X;
    double y = cam.Width / vp.ActualWidth * (pt.Y - vp.ActualHeight / 2) + cam.Position.Y;

    return new Point3D(x, y, 0);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does the opposite of what I need - it moves the frame corners to points defined in `Corners` collection, whereas I need to place the defined points in the `Canvas`' corners.

On an image below, region between rectangle and inner quadrilateral is to be clipped, while contents of the quadrilateral are supposed to be stretched to fit the outer rectangle.
[image: visualization of my intent]

Is there another transformation I have to apply to achieve this? Perhaps there is a simple transformation I can apply to the frame corners coordinates to move defined points there?

Comment: any progress so far?

Answer (score 2):

Using Accord.NET (available as nuget package) you can use the following:

```
Bitmap origin = // this is your quadrilateral bitmap
var corners = new List<IntPoint>(new IntPoint[]
{
    new IntPoint(topLeftPoint), new IntPoint(topRightPoint), new IntPoint(bottomRightPoint), new IntPoint(bottomLeftPoint)
});
var filter = new QuadrilateralTransformation(corners, rect.Width, rect.Height); // rect = your target rectangle size
Bitmap result = filter.Apply(origin); // voila!
```

Comment: Although this seems like a good solution, I cannot easily check it now, because I no longer work on this part of the project. Thanks.